# awk tolower function not working when matching more than one word per line

Tags: regex, awk, lowercase

I have a file seen here:

$ more myfile.txt

Jack and Jill went up the hill.

My question is why tolower() does not get applied to the second word, 'jill', in this case:

$ awk 'tolower($0) ~ /jack/&&/jill/{ print FILENAME ":" $0; }' *.txt

The following work but I want to keep everything lowercase.

$ awk 'tolower($0) ~ /jack/{ print FILENAME ":" $0; }' *.txt

myfile.txt:Jack and Jill went up the hill.

$ awk 'tolower($0) ~ /jill/{ print FILENAME ":" $0; }' *.txt

myfile.txt:Jack and Jill went up the hill.

$ awk 'tolower($0) ~ /jack/&&/Jill/{ print FILENAME ":" $0; }' *.txt

myfile.txt:Jack and Jill went up the hill.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Operator precedence` determines how operators are grouped when different operators appear close by in one expression.

```
~ !~
    Matching, nonmatching.
```

is higher than

```
&&
    Logical “and”.
```

---

You can change your command to

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /jack/ && tolower($0) ~ /Jill/{ print FILENAME ":" $0; }' *.txt
```

Comment: Interesting.  That seems to work, thanks!  But why do I have to constantly add tolower() for each word?  Do you know if there is a simple way to force $0 to be lowercase for the duration of the awk?

Comment: `awk '{$0=tolower($0)}; ...'`

Comment: Or `awk -vIGNORECASE=1 '...'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (gawk and as @kev has already written in his comments):

```
awk -vIGNORECASE=1 '/jack/ && /jill/{print FILENAME ":" tolower($0)}' *.txt
```

N.B.

- `IGNORECASE` set to non zero makes all string patterns and regexp's case independent.
- `tolower(`*string*`)` Returns a **copy** of *string*, with each uppercase character in the string replaced with its corresponding lowercase character.

EDIT:

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0)};/jack/ && /jill/{print FILENAME ":" $0}' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I'm trying to go with awk as the lowest common denominator because I'll need it to work across several versions of linux and I don't know which will have gawk.

Comment: The second solution should work on all variations. However it may mess with whitespace.